# Using window.open from a Backbone js View; losing reference to View functions

Tags: backbone.js, window.opener

I need to launch a new Window from a Backbone View.   My View file is using an HTML template.

The HTML template has this chunk of code:

```
<a id="providerIcons">
        <div style='display:inline-block; padding-right:30px;text-align: center;'><img width='110' height='110' src='app/assets/images/dropboxLogo.jpg' /><br/>DropBox</div>
    </a>
```

My View file sets up an Event mapping:

```
events: {
                "click #providerIcons" : "onProvidersClick"
            },
```

and I have the onProvidersClick also defined in the View:

```
onProvidersClick: function () {
                var URL = "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xyz&response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9098/handleOauth.html";

                **var oauthwindow = window.open(URL, "SignIn", "width=650,height=550,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0");**

                oauthwindow.focus();
                return false;
            },
```

This View file also defines a "saveToken" function:

```
saveToken: function () {
                alert("connectorsmain-view.js; saveToken()");
            }
```

The Window launches fine.  However, there is a callback/redirect from the oAuth process (launched in the new window) and it points to and loads a new HTML file of mine in the Window at the end of the oAuth flow.   That final HTML file, which resides on my server, has script to pass an oAuth access_token back to the original screen that opened the new Window:

```
var access_token = (window.location.hash||window.location.search).match(/access_token=([^&amp;]+)/);

        if(access_token){
            // Save the first match
            access_token = decodeURIComponent(access_token[1]);
            **window.opener.saveToken(access_token);**
            window.close();
        }
```

I'm getting an error that window.opener.saveToken is not a function.   It is not recognizing the "saveToken" fxn at the View file level.

If I define a "saveToken" function in the HTML that is the template for the View, then it works as expected.   But, I want the function in the View file, not in the template file.

Greatly appreciate any thoughts !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var oauthwindow = window.open(URL, "SignIn", "width=650,height=550,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0");**

window.openerView = this;
oauthwindow.focus();
```

Then from the child window:

```
window.opener.openerView.saveToken(access_token);
window.close();
```

Obviously this modifies the global scope in the calling window, so be careful if you expect to have several of these views at the same time.

Another option (which would need to be tested), is to copy the opener view reference into the scope of the opened window, though it's unorthodox and may not work cross-browser

```
var oauthwindow = window.open(URL, "SignIn", "width=650,height=550,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0");**

oauthwindow.openerView = this;
oauthwindow.focus();
```

Then

```
window.openerView.saveToken(access_token);
window.close();
```